# how to pass the text field value from an overlay panel to the parent form

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I am not able to get the value from the text box in the overlay panel to the text box in the main form on clicking the submit button on the overlay panel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"

      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <style>
            .link{

                color:blue;

                font-size: 15px;

            }

            .form{ width: 300px;

                   margin: 0 auto;

            }

            .button{
            }

        </style>

        <title>Calendar</title>
        <script>
            function checkPasswords() {

                alert("hii");

                alert(document.getElementById("form:pass").value);

                alert("test");

                window.opener.document.getElementById("form:pass").value = document.getElementById("overPanel1:newpass").value;

                //  document.getElementById("overPanel1").hide();

                return false;

            }
        </script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form styleClass="form" id="form">
            Username : <p:inputText id="username" 
                                    value="#{userBean.username}">
                <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="7" />
            </p:inputText>

            <h:message for="username" style="color:red" />
            <br />
            <br />
            Password : <p:password id="pass" 
                                   value="#{userBean.password}" />
            <br />
            <p:commandLink styleClass="link" 
                           value="change Password" id="commandlink"
                           style="height:20px" />
            <p:overlayPanel id="overPanel1" 
                            for="commandlink" 
                            dynamic="true" 
                            widgetVar="overpanel" 
                            hideEffect="fade">
                <h:form id="innerform">                    
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="1">
                        New Password     :   <p:password id="newpass"
                                                         value="#{userBean.password}" />
                        <br />
                        <p:commandButton styleClass="button"  
                                         id="change" value="Change" 
                                         onclick=" return checkPasswords();
                                           overpanel.hide()">
                            <!-- <p:ajax event="change" update="pass" partialSubmit="true" /> -->
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>  
            </p:overlayPanel>
            <br />
            <br />
            Date Of Birth : <p:calendar value="#{dateBean.date}"
                                        mode="popup" showOn="button" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="user" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should not use nested forms.

As for your question you need to update the second form after you submit the first for example:

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="user" update="form" />
```